# regarding showing multiple locations in google map in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am implementing application which involves showing multiple locations in a google map in blackberry...

Can anybody provide me a hint ???

Answer (score 1):

for implementing multiple location on Google map first you need create a kml file 
example :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document>
  <Placemark>
   <name>Ottawa</name>
   <description>Ottawa office</description>
   <Point>
    <coordinates>-90.86948943473118,48.25450093195546,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
  <name>Battel Creek</name>
  <description>Battel Creek</description>
  <Point>
     <coordinates>-85.1220703125,42.35042512243457,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
  </Placemark>

  </Document>
</kml>
```

save this file on a server (Extension should be KML) and set that path in the code below:-

```
public void invokeGMaps() {

        int mh = CodeModuleManager.getModuleHandle("GoogleMaps");
          if (mh == 0) {
           try {
            throw new ApplicationManagerException(
              "GoogleMaps isn't installed");
           } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
           }
          }
          String[] args = { };//PUT THE SAVED FILE URL OVER HERE IN DOUBLE QUOTES  
          ApplicationDescriptor ad = CodeModuleManager
            .getApplicationDescriptors(mh)[0];
          ApplicationDescriptor ad2 = new ApplicationDescriptor(ad, args);
          try {
           ApplicationManager.getApplicationManager()
             .runApplication(ad2, true);
          } catch (ApplicationManagerException e) {
           System.out.println(e.getMessage());
          }
         }
```

You need to install google map before implementing these code. you can download google map from here :- m.google.com/maps